# Heroku is saying successful build, but its not working? Deploying a react and ruby on rails

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, deployment

It looks like it's getting something because when I go to my website/users(my backend has users and games) it gives me an empty array for users and permission denied for games(which it should be there are validations). But it just doesn't work at all and I'm new to this I'm confused about where I even troubleshoot this?

[picture of the terminal in order 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cjVu.png)

[picture of the terminal in order 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fb6Bb.png)

[picture of the terminal in order 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hca8a.png)

[picture of the terminal in order 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICi3q.png)

[picture of the terminal in order 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uh18T.png)

[/usersOnWebsite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6RYy.png)

```
zvallarino@DESKTOP-K5VQL0B:~/Development/flyhome/flyhome$ sudo service postgresql start
 * Starting PostgreSQL 12 database server                                                                                                                                                                                             [ OK ]
zvallarino@DESKTOP-K5VQL0B:~/Development/flyhome/flyhome$ whoami
zvallarino
zvallarino@DESKTOP-K5VQL0B:~/Development/flyhome/flyhome$ heroku create flyhome010922
Creating ⬢ flyhome010922... done
https://flyhome010922.herokuapp.com/ | https://git.heroku.com/flyhome010922.git
zvallarino@DESKTOP-K5VQL0B:~/Development/flyhome/flyhome$ heroku buildpacks:add heroku/nodejs --index 1
Buildpack added. Next release on flyhome010922 will use heroku/nodejs.
Run git push heroku main to create a new release using this buildpack.
zvallarino@DESKTOP-K5VQL0B:~/Development/flyhome/flyhome$ heroku buildpacks:add heroku/ruby --index 2
Buildpack added. Next release on flyhome010922 will use:
  1. heroku/nodejs
  2. heroku/ruby
Run git push heroku main to create a new release using these buildpacks.
zvallarino@DESKTOP-K5VQL0B:~/Development/flyhome/flyhome$ git add .
zvallarino@DESKTOP-K5VQL0B:~/Development/flyhome/flyhome$ git commit -m "I have faith this time"
On branch main
nothing to commit, working tree clean
zvallarino@DESKTOP-K5VQL0B:~/Development/flyhome/flyhome$ git push heroku main
Enumerating objects: 980, done.
Counting objects: 100% (980/980), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (493/493), done.
Writing objects: 100% (980/980), 473.44 KiB | 7.07 MiB/s, done.
Total 980 (delta 701), reused 561 (delta 472), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpacks:
remote:        1. heroku/nodejs
remote:        2. heroku/ruby
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version 14.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 14.18.2...
remote:        Using default npm version: 6.14.15
remote:
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules
remote:        added 0 packages in 0.027s
remote:
remote: -----> Build
remote:
remote: -----> Caching build
remote:        - node_modules (nothing to cache)
remote:
remote: -----> Pruning devDependencies
remote:        up to date in 0.456s
remote:        found 0 vulnerabilities
remote:
remote:
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Installing bundler 2.2.33
remote: -----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.7.4
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.2.33
remote:        Running: BUNDLE_WITHOUT='development:test' BUNDLE_PATH=vendor/bundle BUNDLE_BIN=vendor/bundle/bin BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT=1 bundle install -j4
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
remote:        Fetching rake 13.0.6
remote:        Installing rake 13.0.6
remote:        Fetching concurrent-ruby 1.1.9
remote:        Fetching minitest 5.15.0
remote:        Fetching zeitwerk 2.5.1
remote:        Fetching builder 3.2.4
remote:        Installing zeitwerk 2.5.1
remote:        Installing builder 3.2.4
remote:        Installing minitest 5.15.0
remote:        Fetching erubi 1.10.0
remote:        Installing concurrent-ruby 1.1.9
remote:        Installing erubi 1.10.0
remote:        Fetching racc 1.6.0
remote:        Fetching crass 1.0.6
remote:        Fetching rack 2.2.3
remote:        Installing racc 1.6.0 with native extensions
remote:        Installing rack 2.2.3
remote:        Installing crass 1.0.6
remote:        Fetching nio4r 2.5.8
remote:        Fetching websocket-extensions 0.1.5
remote:        Installing nio4r 2.5.8 with native extensions
remote:        Installing websocket-extensions 0.1.5
remote:        Fetching marcel 1.0.2
remote:        Fetching mini_mime 1.1.2
remote:        Installing marcel 1.0.2
remote:        Installing mini_mime 1.1.2
remote:        Fetching jsonapi-renderer 0.2.2
remote:        Fetching bcrypt 3.1.16
remote:        Installing jsonapi-renderer 0.2.2
remote:        Installing bcrypt 3.1.16 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching msgpack 1.4.2
remote:        Installing msgpack 1.4.2 with native extensions
remote:        Using bundler 2.2.33
remote:        Fetching method_source 1.0.0
remote:        Installing method_source 1.0.0
remote:        Fetching pg 1.2.3
remote:        Installing pg 1.2.3 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching thor 1.1.0
remote:        Installing thor 1.1.0
remote:        Fetching rack-test 1.1.0
remote:        Installing rack-test 1.1.0
remote:        Fetching websocket-driver 0.7.5
remote:        Installing websocket-driver 0.7.5 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching i18n 1.8.11
remote:        Installing i18n 1.8.11
remote:        Fetching tzinfo 2.0.4
remote:        Installing tzinfo 2.0.4
remote:        Fetching sprockets 4.0.2
remote:        Installing sprockets 4.0.2
remote:        Fetching mail 2.7.1
remote:        Installing mail 2.7.1
remote:        Fetching nokogiri 1.12.5 (x86_64-linux)
remote:        Installing nokogiri 1.12.5 (x86_64-linux)
remote:        Fetching puma 5.5.2
remote:        Installing puma 5.5.2 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching activesupport 6.1.4.3
remote:        Installing activesupport 6.1.4.3
remote:        Fetching loofah 2.13.0
remote:        Installing loofah 2.13.0
remote:        Fetching bootsnap 1.9.3
remote:        Installing bootsnap 1.9.3 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
remote:        Installing rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
remote:        Fetching globalid 1.0.0
remote:        Installing globalid 1.0.0
remote:        Fetching activemodel 6.1.4.3
remote:        Installing activemodel 6.1.4.3
remote:        Fetching case_transform 0.2
remote:        Installing case_transform 0.2
remote:        Fetching rails-html-sanitizer 1.4.2
remote:        Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.4.2
remote:        Fetching activejob 6.1.4.3
remote:        Installing activejob 6.1.4.3
remote:        Fetching activerecord 6.1.4.3
remote:        Installing activerecord 6.1.4.3
remote:        Fetching actionview 6.1.4.3
remote:        Installing actionview 6.1.4.3
remote:        Fetching actionpack 6.1.4.3
remote:        Installing actionpack 6.1.4.3
remote:        Fetching actioncable 6.1.4.3
remote:        Fetching activestorage 6.1.4.3
remote:        Installing activestorage 6.1.4.3
remote:        Installing actioncable 6.1.4.3
remote:        Fetching actionmailer 6.1.4.3
remote:        Installing actionmailer 6.1.4.3
remote:        Fetching active_model_serializers 0.10.12
remote:        Installing active_model_serializers 0.10.12
remote:        Fetching railties 6.1.4.3
remote:        Installing railties 6.1.4.3
remote:        Fetching sprockets-rails 3.4.2
remote:        Installing sprockets-rails 3.4.2
remote:        Fetching actionmailbox 6.1.4.3
remote:        Installing actionmailbox 6.1.4.3
remote:        Fetching actiontext 6.1.4.3
remote:        Installing actiontext 6.1.4.3
remote:        Fetching rails 6.1.4.3
remote:        Installing rails 6.1.4.3
remote:        Bundle complete! 10 Gemfile dependencies, 49 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups 'development' and 'test' were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into `./vendor/bundle`
remote:        Bundle completed (19.43s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: -----> Detecting rails configuration
remote:
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:
remote:        There is a more recent Ruby version available for you to use:
remote:
remote:        2.7.5
remote:
remote:        The latest version will include security and bug fixes. We always recommend
remote:        running the latest version of your minor release.
remote:
remote:        Please upgrade your Ruby version.
remote:
remote:        For all available Ruby versions see:
remote:          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes
remote:
remote:
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types     -> release, web
remote:        Default types for buildpack -> console, rake
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 62.3M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:  !     Release command declared: this new release will not be available until the command succeeds.
remote:        Released v6
remote:        https://flyhome010922.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
remote: Running release command...
remote:
remote: I, [2022-01-09T18:38:11.135797 #16]  INFO -- : Migrating to CreateUsers (20211215192349)
remote: == 20211215192349 CreateUsers: migrating ======================================
remote: -- create_table(:users)
remote:    -> 0.0131s
remote: == 20211215192349 CreateUsers: migrated (0.0132s) =============================
remote:
remote: I, [2022-01-09T18:38:11.163117 #16]  INFO -- : Migrating to CreateGames (20211216234121)
remote: == 20211216234121 CreateGames: migrating ======================================
remote: -- create_table(:games)
remote:    -> 0.0105s
remote: == 20211216234121 CreateGames: migrated (0.0105s) =============================
remote:
remote: I, [2022-01-09T18:38:11.180094 #16]  INFO -- : Migrating to CreateGameTables (20211216234129)
remote: == 20211216234129 CreateGameTables: migrating =================================
remote: -- create_table(:game_tables)
remote:    -> 0.0202s
remote: == 20211216234129 CreateGameTables: migrated (0.0202s) ========================
remote:
remote: I, [2022-01-09T18:38:11.206719 #16]  INFO -- : Migrating to CreateHighscores (20211216234153)
remote: == 20211216234153 CreateHighscores: migrating =================================
remote: -- create_table(:highscores)
remote:    -> 0.0201s
remote: == 20211216234153 CreateHighscores: migrated (0.0202s) ========================
remote:
remote: Waiting for release.... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/flyhome010922.git
 * [new branch]      main -> main
```

```
zvallarino@DESKTOP-K5VQL0B:~/Development/flyhome/flyhome$ heroku run rails db:migrate
Running rails db:migrate on ⬢ flyhome010922... up, run.1737 (Free)
zvallarino@DESKTOP-K5VQL0B:~/Development/flyhome/flyhome$ heroku run rails db:seed
Running rails db:seed on ⬢ flyhome010922... up, run.6674 (Free)
"done seeding yo"
zvallarino@DESKTOP-K5VQL0B:~/Development/flyhome/flyhome$ heroku open
 ▸    Error opening web browser.
 ▸    Error: Exited with code 3
 ▸
 ▸    Manually visit https://flyhome010922.herokuapp.com/ in your browser.
```

Resolution was to add the scripts

```
 "engines": {
    "node": "16.x"
  },
 "scripts": {
    "build": "npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client",
    "clean": "rm -rf public",
    "deploy": "cp -a client/build/. public/",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run clean && npm run build && npm run deploy"
  }
```

Comment: Can you please copy-and-paste the log to your question? that makes it searchable and people who want to help you can easier search for parts of the output.

Comment: @spickermann done. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: What doesn't work? Can you give details? Can you access the `heroku console`? From there, can you query the data directly?

Comment: @Jad the frontend website doesnt show up. So it should pull up the frontend react, but it just says "This flyhome010922.herokuapp.com page can’t be found" but to your point, I did try the heroku console. It does say it has four games, thus the backend is working.The frontend is not? My frontend and backend are in the same repository if you need that information. and ty for the help

Comment: @Jad got it. ty your comment is what I needed. I didn't have the scripts

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: @Zach no probs mate. Please add in a detailed answer, so that anyone else who finds this question might be able to solve a similar issue

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I'm facing the same issue. The route does not go to the React app, it goes to the backend app and fails with a 404 error because it is a frontend-only route.